# How to extract serial from SSL certificate

Tags: openssl

I'd like to know what is the best way to extract serial number from a SSL certificate formatted in PEM format.

After that I'd like to format the certificate in following format `hexhex:hexhex:...:hexhex`
so for example if my serial number of the SSL certificate in hexadecimal is

```
0123456709AB
```

the output should be

```
01:23:45:67:09:AB
```

For preference I'd like to acomplish this using openssl with the x509 option using one single line UNIX command

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try:

```
openssl x509 -noout -serial -in cert.pem | cut -d'=' -f2 | sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//'
```

`openssl x509 -noout -serial -in cert.pem` will output the serial number of the certificate, but in the format `serial=0123456709AB`.

It is therefore piped to `cut -d'=' -f2` which splits the output on the equal sign and outputs the second part - `0123456709AB`.

That is sent to `sed`.  The first part of the `sed` command `s/../&:/g` splits the string every two characters (`..`) and inserts a colon (`:`).  This results in `01:23:45:67:89:AB:` (note the colon on the end).

The second part of the `sed` command (`s/:$//`) searches for a colon at the end of the output and replaces it with an empty string, resulting in the desired output.

---

Or for a `openssl` and `sed` only answer:

```
openssl x509 -noout -serial -in test2.crt |  sed 's/.*=//g;s/../&:/g;s/:$//'
```

The addition of `s/.*=//g` at the start of the `sed` command replaces the `cut` in the first version.

Answer (score 0):

`openssl x509 -noout -text -in [cert]`
is getting you more info about the cert, and if you want just the serial, you can grep for that there, ie.

`... | grep -A1 "Serial Number"`

This would give generate output like:

```
Serial Number:
            07:bf:0e:14:95:e7:1e:34:a2:b1:8b:df:ca:dd:ab:af:af:fb:50:fb
```

to remove the `Serial Number:` text add a `tail -1`

The full command would then be:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in [cert] | grep -A1 "Serial Number" | tail -1
```

Comment: No need to fight :-) You can provide your own answer even if the question already has an accepted one. However you should [formulate the answer properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to ensure it won't get deleted - partial answers like this do. I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/) to learn how these sites work.